# Java favorite refactoring techniques

Tags: java, refactoring

There are some common code patterns I find in other people's Java code that can benefit from some simple refactoring.

What are your pet code pattern hates and their fixes (and the reason if it isn't obvious)?

I have taken to liberty of answering with a couple of my own pet hates.

Comment: Quote from the FAQ: *"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."* Please try to rephrase your question accordingly.

Comment: Agree with Péter Török. To make it worse, you answer your own "question" with two almost identical answers.

Comment: Yes, but they're are *not* the same. They are different refactorings

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
boolean someMethod() {
    if (<some test>) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

replace with

```
boolean someMethod() {
    return <some test>;
}
```

Guiding principles/patterns:

- less code is good
- redundant code is bad

Comment: Why don't you merge your 2 answers? It would be easier and less confusing for the readers. If we have a complete answer, instead of searching through all answer to have a complete one.

Answer (score 17):

One of my favourite refactoring is using Strategy pattern instead of long if-else/switch statments.
Eg.

```
String chooser = ""//some sting

if(testCond1(chooser)){
doSomething1();
} else if(testCond2(chooser)){
doSomethingElse2();
} else if(testCond2(chooser)){
doSomethingElse3();
} else if(testCond4(chooser)){
doSomethingElse4();
} else if(testCond5(chooser)){
doSomethingElse5();
} else if(testCond6(chooser)){
doSomethingElse6();
}
```

Can be changed to:

```
    Map<String, Handler> handlers = new HashMap<String, Handler>();

handlers.get(chooser).handle();
```

then we define a Handler interface

```
interface Handler{
    handle();
}
```

And for each condition we have a new class that implements the handler.

```
class CondOne implements Handler{
    handle(){
        //some code
    }
}
```

Pros. Object oriented approch, code is easier to maintain. It is also easy to add new conditions without changing the important parts of the code.

Comment: Where is it recommended to put handlers into `handlers` map and how to do it?

Answer (score 7):

```
void someMethod(SomeClass param) {
    if (param != null) { // or some other test
        // Rest of method code
    }
}
```

replace with:

```
void someMethod(SomeClass param) {
    if (param == null) { // or some other test
        return; // or throw exception if test expected to "always" pass
    }
    // Rest of method code
}
```

Guiding principles/patterns:

- less indentation is good
- shorter if blocks are good
- parameter checking should be done early and exit on problem, rather than allowing code to execute on passing

Comment: Actually you could raise an exception instead of just returning if a null parameter doesnt make sense.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (<some test>) {
    return someObject;
} else {
    return someOtherObject;
}
```

replace with:

```
if (<some test>) {
    return someObject;
}

return someOtherObject;
```

or for even more brevity and if the line isn't too long (ie you aren't creating the objects in-line):

```
return <some test> ? someObject : someOtherObject;
```

Guiding principles/patterns:

- less code is good
- redundant code is bad - when an if returns, there is no need for an "else"
- less indentation is good

Comment: I would refactor your code :)

I Always put curly braces on if statments.

Comment: IMO it sucks. You introduce return statement that is similar to goto. I would do sth like that instead:  

SomeObject o = something;
if(test){
  o = sth;
}

Comment: I'd rewrite it using ternary opearator like this: 
return <some test> ? someObject : someOtherObject;

Comment: @amenoire I already did rewrite it like that when I posted the original answer; exactly your suggested code was posted in the answer 4 years ago

Answer (score 1):

I like enums and try to refactor code with a lot of string checks.

```
if (str.equals("A") {...}
else if (str.equals("B") {...}
else if (str.equals("C") {...}
```

to

```
switch (str){
 case A: ... ; break;
 case B: ... ; break;
 case C: ... ; break;
```

}

Comment: Java 7 should eliminate that need. It introduces switch on Strings. I believe NetBeans is capable of detected nested if-else constructs with String checks and turn those into switch statements.

Comment: I would use a design pattern like strategy or chain of responsibilities instead. Long switch statments suck in general.

Answer (score 0):

Often I see code like this, when not references should be compared, but content.

```
if (someObject == anotherObject) {
   doSomething();
}
```

So I replace it with (and if necessary override equals() and hashCode()) :

```
if (someObject.equals(anotherObject))  {
   doSomething();
}
```

Comment: this is not just plain 'refactor', it's bug fixing.